# Discord Interprocess Communication - Read Messages

Tags: discord, discord.js, ipc, rpc, discord-jda

I'd like to abide by TOS but i am having tough time. I'm in paid server where I can't place a bot account. I simply want to consume the message content in my application (currently in python). What can I do? Can I write a hook to consume the messages from the GUI or from the web client? It seems what I want to do is not supported. Any thoughts?

Others have stated that you can apparently use use ipc and messages.read scope or RPC to receive messages but I don't know what resources are available to hook into and get the message content as it comes from the server.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to read the messages from the client. You could use the **Discord API** with your account's token, but this is **not allowed by the Discord ToS** and thus is bannable *(self botting)*. The other way is to use **Discord IPC**.

Discord IPC allows you to **communicate with the Discord client** by using named pipes. The default name is `discord-ipc-0`. You need a Discord application to use it.

The IPC protocol uses the same protocol as RPC, which is documented on [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc). You can also find more information on the IPC protocol on the [discord-rpc official repo](https://github.com/discord/discord-rpc).

To put it simply, the packets you send through the pipe are serialized that way:

```
uint32 opcode
uint32 length
byte[length] jsonData
```

The data is a JSON encoded object, with a unique `nonce` parameter that is sent back on the answer, a `cmd` parameter for the command you want to use and optionally `args` and `evt`.

You would probably be interested in the **AUTHORIZE**, **AUTHENTICATE**, **GET_CHANNEL** and **SUBSCRIBE** commands. So I'll explain those four commands here.

But first, you need to connect to the IPC and do the handshake. This is done by sending a message with the **opcode 0, your client_id and the protocol version**. Here's what the JSON object should look like:

```json
{
    "v": 1,
    "client_id": 332269999912132097
}
```

Once you're connected, you should receive a **DISPATCH response** with the user info. Every message you will send from this point should use the **opcode 1**

Now, you need to send an **AUTHORIZE command** This command allows you to ask an **OAuth2 code** from the client with the specified **scopes**, which will allow you to use the **AUTHENTICATE command**. Here, you would want the **rpc** and **messages.read** scopes. It should look like this:

```json
{
    "nonce": "be9a6de3-31d0-4767-a8e9-4818c5690015",
    "cmd": "AUTHORIZE",
    "args": {
        "client_id": 332269999912132097,
        "scopes": "rpc messages.read"
    }
}
```

**Please note that you need a redirect uri on your application for this to work.**

The client should get a prompt. If he accepts, then your application would receive an **oauth2 code** that you can use to authenticate. The OAuth2 process is explained on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant).

After making your request to `/oauth2/token` with **the code, your client id, client secret and redirect uri**, you should be getting an **access token** that you can to authenticate, using the **AUTHENTICATE** command. Here is what it should look like:

```json
{
    "nonce": "5dc0c062-98c6-47a0-8922-bbb52e9d6afa",
    "cmd": "AUTHENTICATE",
    "args": {
        "access_token": "CZhtkLDpNYXgPH9Ml6shqh2OwykChw"
    }
}
```

If the authentication is successful, you should receive a response with `evt` set to `null`, application info and user info.

From this point, you are authenticated and you can read messages by using the **GET_CHANNEL command** to get the last messages, and by subscribing to the **MESSAGE_CREATE event** to get the new messages when they're sent. Those are documented on the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc).

Comment: This was the only information source I was able to find about the Discord IPC protol. Thank you very much. Thanks to your answer, I was able to make this Discord IPC library for Qt: https://github.com/CZDanol/QtDiscordIPC